# React Native Enzyme testing useEffect hook testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, enzyme

I have a `useEffect` hook inside my component. I'm testing with Enzyme. Not sure how I can test the functions calls inside the hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    onChangeText(initialLocation.displayName);
    setAutocomplete(null);
}, [initialLocation]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect hook is listening to changes from the `initialLocation` prop.  So to test this, you should test the entire component using something like jest, or react testing library.  Change the value of `initialLocation` and make assertions as to how the component should react to those prop changes.  I obviously can't see your entire component in this example, but you could make the assertion that the correct `displayName` can be found in the dom tree when changing the prop